# How to indent the function parameters after an open parenthesis in js file correctly using VIM?

Tags: javascript, vim

When I'm writing a invoke with long parameters, e.g.

```
foo_bar(foo,
bar);
```

The web-indent plugin will format the js files to:

```
foo_bar(foo,
<tab>bar;
```

But what I want is:

```
foo_bar(foo,
        bar);
```

Already searched vim.org, seems no easy solutian.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little bit of testing it looks like you probably want to `set cinoptions+=(0`.  This seems to work for the simple case but there may be some edge cases that you'd have to handle with the other `cinoptions`.

See `:help cinoptions` and `:help cinoptions-values` for more info.